# Laravel - selecting rows based on unique date

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to select one row for each unique date in Laravel. I have working SQL query but I can't make it work in Laravel.

Working query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `stats` 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `stats` GROUP BY DATE(created_at))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make laravel query with 2 different ways
1. Eloquent:just create model for stats table and write below query

```
     Stats::whereIn('id', function($q){
      $q->select(DB::RAW('max(id)'))
      ->from('stats')
      ->groupBy(DB::RAW('DATE(created_at)'))
     })->get();
```

2. Call by table name

   ```
   DB::table('stats')->whereIn('id', function($q){
     $q->select(DB::RAW('max(id)'))
    ->from('stats')
    ->groupBy(DB::RAW('DATE(created_at)'))
   })->get();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query in laravel

```
DB::table('stats')
    whereIn('id', function($query){
    $query->select(DB::RAW('max(id)'))
    ->from('stats')
    ->groupBy(DB::RAW('DATE(created_at)'))
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM stats GROUP BY 
        DATE(created_at))";
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel very well, but here is a query which should give you what you what you need:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM stats t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT created_at, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM stats
    GROUP BY created_at
) t2
    ON t1.created_at = t2.created_at AND
       t1.id         = t2.max_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do whereRaw easily in laravel to keep your syntax aligned with standard

$results = State::whereRaw('id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `stats` GROUP BY DATE(created_at))')->get();

Note: State is App\State Model
this will do the job